# How does Visual Studio Code detect Typescript errors without compiling

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How does Visual Studio Code detect Typescript errors within the editor without compiling?

According to this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

> Visual Studio Code includes TypeScript language support but does not
>   include the TypeScript compiler, tsc. You will need to install the
>   TypeScript compiler either globally or in your workspace to transpile
>   TypeScript source code to JavaScript (tsc HelloWorld.ts).

Is VSC compiling "on-the-fly" in order to detect errors? Am little confused how it manages to be helpful without doing any compiling. Also, how do I know the TS version VSC is running?

Comment: The typescript compiler includes an api that is used by all of the main editors to provide the language support. Compilation happens incrementally in the background as you edit.

Comment: But for this to work, I must have the typescript compiler installed in order to for VSC to make use of the API? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, but Visual Studio Code ships with a version of typescript included. Alternatively you can tell it to use another version.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Comment: Oh I see. Started to make since. Didn't realise VSC also had its own TSC compiler